# Property of Alternating $k$-Linear Functions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

I have trouble understanding the proof of Lemma 3.14 from Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds*.

**Lemma 3.14.** If $f$ is an alternating $k$-linear function on a vector space $V$, then $Af = (k!)f.$

*Proof.* Since for alternating $f$ we have $\sigma f = (\mathrm{sgn}\,\sigma)f$, and $\mathrm{sgn}\,\sigma$ is $\pm 1$, we must have

$$
Af = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k} (\mathrm{sgn}\,\sigma) \, \sigma f = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k} (\mathrm{sgn}\,\sigma) \, (\mathrm{sgn}\,\sigma) f = (k!) f.
$$

**My Question**

How do we get the last step with $k!$ in it from the 3rd step with two $(\mathrm{sgn}\,\sigma)$ in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $\sigma \in S_k$, we have that $(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma)^2 = 1$. Thus, 
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_k} (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) f = \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} f = \Big( \sum_{\sigma \in S_k}1 \Big) f$$
and since there are $k!$ possible permutations in $S_k$, in the latter we are adding $k!$ times the number $1$.